# remove dynamically added row in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to delete a dynamically added table row using jqueryn but it is'nt working. Can anyone help me?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.removeFile', function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  var file = elem.data('file');
  var tr = elem.closest('tr');

  bootbox.confirm('Weet je zeker dat je het bestand wilt verwijderen?', function(result) {
    if (result) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ route('media.remove') }}',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
          file: file
        },
        success: function(data) {
          elem.closest('tr').remove();
        }
      });
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Please show your HTML code.

Comment: Have you checked to ensure your AJAX request is returning a successful response code?

Comment: it isn't working covers a lot of ground, please can you narrow it down